# Grunt error: Tasks directory "tasks" not found

Tags: gruntjs

When I try to run Grunt in OS X Mavericks 10.9 Terminal by entering grunt and return I receive the following error message:

```
    >> Tasks directory "tasks" not found.

    Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
    ERROR: Can't find config file: .jshintrc
    Jim-MacBookPro:MyDirectory jmpreston$ grunt
    >> Tasks directory "tasks" not found.
```

If I enter grunt -tasks I see the following along with the tasks directory error above:

```
    TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
        at path.js:360:15
        at Array.filter (native)
        at Object.exports.join (path.js:358:36)
        at Object.file.exists
    (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyDirectory/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/file.js:373:28)
        at task.loadTasks 
    (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyDirectory/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:364:18)
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at Task.task.init
    (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyDirectory/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:450:33)
        at Object.grunt.tasks
    (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyDirectory/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:113:8)
        at Object.module.exports [as cli]        
    (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyDirectory/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/cli.js:38:9)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt:45:20)
```

Grunt seems to understand that it needs to look in the /node_modules/ folders and those exist with the original install.  I installed Grunt after Compass and Foundation 5.  There is no tasks folder with the original install.  I checked the Grunt docs + searched the Web and no help anywhere.  One guy mentioned on Stack Overflow that he had this problem and then answered that he fixed it without saying how.

grunt-cli v0.1.13

I'm not much of a coder but can usually read and hack js and php.  This is my first time with Foundation / Compass / Grunt.  I have Git and GitHub working fine.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Could you post your Gruntfile and node.js version?

Comment: There is no version in the Gruntfile and I don't know how to get Node's version but they were both downloaded in the last few days.

Comment: `node -v` will get your node.js version number. Could you post your gruntfile?

Comment: Node.js is v0.10.26.  I don't see a way to post the whole grunt file.js But it came from here a few days ago.  https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass

Comment: I have a thought.  All this is new to me so I'm a little confused but I think I installed grunt with terminal and npm, not downloading directly from Github.  It seems that these should be the same files but maybe not.

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect that the problem is in gruntfile.js.  I'm trying to understand what this code is doing.  So far I haven't seen instructions to create a /tasks folder or what to put in it.

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: {
      name: 'grunt-contrib-compass'
    },
    jshint: {
      all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        'tasks/*.js',
        '<%= nodeunit.tests %>'
      ],
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
      }
    },

Comment: You can gist your gruntfile here: https://gist.github.com/ It sounds like a misconfiguration in your Gruntfile. Such as the statement `grunt.loadTasks('tasks')` which is for loading custom tasks from a folder named `tasks/`. Seeing a full Gruntfile is the only real way for me to help debug the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

The full gruntfile.js that is downloaded from github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass contains a lot of code that may not be useful.  My mistake was to think that this code related to the setup process as would be the case with a normal software setup.

What is confusing to a noobie is that the process of setting up grunt in Terminal / command line doesn't set up the tasks and tasks folder that are in the downloaded gruntfile.  I may not have my head around this completely yet but there seems to be no direct connection between the initial setup and the files on Github.  The code on Github are only examples and need to be removed or hacked into usefulness.

Thank you @Kyle for helping me sort this out!